# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib, while building tensorflow on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, tensorflow, building

I am building tensorflow on my Mac(an hackintosh, so I have a GPU, and already installed CUDA8.0. It works fine with building caffe, so I am sure it works.) I have already set up the environment variables as following(I have put these in `.zshrc`,`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`):

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib:$CUDA_HOME/extras/CUPTI/lib"
```

`./configure` works fine. Then I start build using command `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`.
Then I got this error:

```
    ERROR: /Development/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:572:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow/python:array_ops_pygenrule failed: bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.AbnormalTerminationException: Process terminated by signal 5.
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_zarzen/bdf1cb43f3ff02468b610730bd03f348/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_array_ops_py_wrappers_cc
  Reason: image not found
/bin/bash: line 1: 92702 Trace/BPT trap: 5       bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_array_ops_py_wrappers_cc @tensorflow/python/ops/hidden_ops.txt 1 > bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

I can make sure the missed library is there. And I also tried install pre-built binary(I know it only support CUDA7.5, so I set up the PATH to point to CUDA7.5, but it doesn't work. when I try to `import tensorflow`, similar error `Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib`, only version number changed).

I don't know why it cannot find the `lib`. Anyone can help? or any suggestions?

Comment: I've seen SIP interfere with rpath dyld loading, you could try disabling it if you are on El Capitan (system integrity protection)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? Same error here.

Comment: no, but follow the instructions by Vijay below, can lead you pass the build phase. however in `import` stage still cannot find the `dylib`

Comment: disable SIP do help!

Comment: You can find a tuto to build TensorFlow on macOS + a lot more discussions on this topic on this github thread : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9072#issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should fix the error.

Find the file "genrule-setup.sh". The file should be in

```
<tensorflow source dir>/bazel-tensorflow/external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/
```

If the timestamp of this file changes then bazel build will fail saying the file is corrupted. So before modifying this file make a note of the timestamp

```
stat genrule-setup.sh
```

You should get an output like this:

```
16777220 25929227 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user wheel 0 242 "Oct 12 23:46:28 2016" "Oct 10 21:49:39 2026" "Oct 12 21:49:39 2016" "Oct 12 21:49:38 2016" 4096 8 0 genrule-setup.sh
```

Note down the second timestamp "Oct 10 21:49:39 2026" from the above output

edit the genrule-setup.sh file

```
nano genrule-setup.sh
```

and add the environment configuration to the end of the file

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

save and close the editor.

Then change the timestamp to the original timestamp

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm.SS genrule-setup.sh
```

for e.g.

```
touch -t 202610102149.39 genrule-setup.sh
```

Finally, create a symbolic link to avoid "Segmentation fault: 11" error

```
ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.1.dylib
```

Now restart the build

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: Now I can build. But after build and installation. I try to import tensorflow, again `image not found`; ```

Comment: detailed `ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib`

Comment: check if DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable is set to /usr/local/cuda/lib. also check the /usr/local/cuda/lib folder contains libcudart.8.0.dylib

Comment: Confirmed that DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to `/usr/local/cuda/lib` and `libcudart.8.0.dylib` is there. Also I have checked the `python` path, I have set `PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow//python:$PYTHONPATH"`

Comment: After `ImportError` there is another error, which I forgot mention: `Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.`

Comment: as the error message says, you should not run python from the tensorflow directory. change to a different directory and try it again

Comment: are you running some third party library or application using Tensorflow? To check if tensorflow is installed properly run `python -c "import tensorflow as f"` and see if there are no error messages

Comment: It has the error `ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter`. I don't have third party lib, I just want to run tensoflow GPU version

Comment: When do you get this error? I mean which program or code are you running to test tensorflow GPU?

Comment: No other code, I just want to `import tensorflow` under `python REPL`

Comment: after the build, I hope you installed it with the following command
```sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl```

Sometimes you might see CUDA 3.0 compatibility issue which can be resolved by selecting 3.0,3.5 when running the ./configure script

What is your OSX version and GPU card?

Comment: I have installed using that command. I am using CUDA8.0, and I am pretty sure that I have chosen the right version at `./configure` phase. The Cudnn version is 5, and it already installed in `/usr/local/cuda/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

When running ./configure, make sure you specify the correct cuda version. You can find this out by running:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version
```

You can pass environment variables to bazel during build using the `action_env` flag.

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda \
    --action_env=DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib \
    //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html